# Is there a way to assign a script custom attribute the value of a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to dynamically assign a scripts custom attribute to the value of a variable. I'm trying to do this as I want to pass a products SKU to it.

I've tried a variable as I normally would but when I save it the browser automatically adds quotes around the variable name making it past the variable name as a string.

```
<script>
var test = "SKU";
</script>
<script src="website" defer="defer" data-custom-vars=test>
```

Doing the above I was expecting

```
<script src="website" defer="defer" data-custom-vars="SKU">
```

but instead I get

```
<script src="website" defer="defer" data-custom-vars="test">
```

I'm using a 3rd party tool for the script src part.

Are there any other alternative methods available to achieve something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, your script tag has the `defer` attribute, so it won't run until after the page has loaded. So, if you run Javascript immediately after the script tag in the HTML, you can refer to the above script tag and change its `custom-vars` data attribute, and once the deferred script loads, it will see that it has the desired `custom-vars` attribute:

```
<script id="deferredScript" src="website" defer="defer"></script>
<script>
  var test = "SKU";
  document.getElementById('deferredScript').dataset.customVars = test;
</script>
```

You could do it in one go with `document.write`, but `document.write` is generally considered to be pretty poor practice, given other available methods.